# My max-width:1140px is not working it cannot be in center my margin:0 auto

Tags: html, css

i am using the `max-width: 1140px` on the div amd use `margin:0 auto` it is not working in the pc , on the other hand my instructor using it it works in his laptop

i tried with 900px then it working even not working on 1000px

```css
.divs{
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="divs">
    <h1>max-width</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set  `.divs` to max-width greater than body, it takes the width of body, thus  `margin: 0 auto` does nothing.

When max-width is smaller than `<body>`, width of `.divs` is effectively smaller than `<body>`, thus `margin: 0 auto` works.

This should explain why it works on some resolution and not on others.

```css
.divs-1140px{
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.divs-300px{
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Added new example using percentage */
.divs-percentage {
    max-width: 70%; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}


div {
  background: green;
}

body {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="divs-1140px">
    <h1>Larger than body</h1>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="divs-300px">
    <h1>Smaller Than body</h1>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="divs-percentage">
    <h1>Using Percentage</h1>
  </div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: Body width is 100% by default, this does not answer the question.

Comment: I agree that it is irrelevant and had edited that out.

Comment: but i saw tutorial he used width 1140px for section part and use margin 0 auto its working in his pc fine? what is the proper solution for it can i use 100% instead of 1140px?

Comment: This may be due to his <body> is larger than the max width 1140px. Even if you have used max-width: 100%; it will still inherit the width of <body> and thus margin will have no effect . 

One thing you can try on your example, CTRL + Scroll Down to zoom out on your browser to increase the width of the body. Then see if margin-auto works.

Comment: You can try anything lesser than 100%, see my updated code snippet using max-width: 70%;